# jQueryUI - switchClass - how do I remove any class that happens to be applied, rather than needing to stipulate the class that needs removing?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I'm using switchClass (with UI) to change classes on an element.

As defined here - http://jqueryui.com/demos/switchClass/ - the method goes

```
switchClass( remove, add, [duration] )
```

Is there some sort of selector I can use to not have to stipulate the class that needs to be removed?

Something like...

```
switchClass( '*', 'newclass', slow )
```

I was initially chaining everything like this...

```
$('body').removeClass().addClass('newClass')
```

but that breaks my animation between the classes.

**Resolved**

In my case I was able to use

```
animate({ backgroundColor: target_colour }, 500)
```

rather than changing the class...

If anyone knows how to do the switchClass magic I'm sure it will come in handy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('body').switchClass( $('body').attr('className'), 'newclass', 'slow' )
```

;)